# Entity Framework - How to make async operations inside the same transaction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I am trying to make a batch insertion for users run in parallel, by creating a new DbContext for each insert operation. The operations are actually running async, as expected, but now they are not under the transaction that I wish them to be under.

This is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
using (IDbContextTransaction transaction = this.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        var tasks = new List<Task>();
                        foreach (User user in users)
                        {
                            var _localContext = new ApplicantContext(this.Options, this.Logger);
                            tasks.Add(_localContext.AddUser(user));
                        }

                        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

                        await transaction.CommitAsync();
                        return "Success";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
```

I want to make all the operations under `tasks` run inside the same transaction, in a way that whenever one of throws an exception, the transaction is rolled back, and no user is inserted.

How can I do that?

PS: I'm creating a new context for each operation, because if I use the same, I get `A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed` error.

Comment: For this operation you don't need any transaction and creating new context for each instance at all. Use a common algorithm. It will give the same result only much faster and safer.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any transaction, just use AddRange. it will roll back if there is an error in any user record

```
 var _localContext = new ApplicantContext(this.Options, this.Logger);
 _localContext.Users.AddRange(users);
 await _localContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```